# luatodonotes / tikz: How to redesign the node of \todo?

Tags: tikz-pgf

For the following, how may I

1- have a line break and control the alignment of the text inside the todo node?

2- make some visually better way of separating the author from the comment below (e.g. have two separate adjacent rounded boxes above each other)?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatodonotes}
\begin{document}
    \todo[author = the author,  noline , color = orange]{the comment}{\color{blue}{the highlighted text}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had a quick look at it. I think the cleanest way would be to make a feature request to the author. Adding a frame around the author is as simple as `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatodonotes}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\begin{document}
    \todo[author = \Circled{the author},  noline , color = orange]{the comment}{\textcolor{blue}{the highlighted text}}
\end{document}`. Everything else is much more cumbersome because this is (sorry to say this) a wild mix of pgf keys and other keys.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks for your consideration.